# Movie I watched about an underground lab under a mansion

Tags: story-identification, movie

It’s about a maid (or nanny) who comes to work for the lady of the mansion and her daughter. I think the lady of the mansion is pregnant and her husband is not home.

Somehow the maid discovers something strange that is going on with the house and (this part is maybe the maid's imagination) she discovers a lift inside the house that brings her to an underground lab where people are cut up.

The final scene is of the owners vacating the house and the daughter going back to the house to retrieve something from a room and seeing the maid rocking a baby back and forth. Both the maid and baby have white eyes (with no iris).

I know the details are fudged but this is the best I can remember! The last scene details are correct though.

Comment: This may seem silly to you, but what part of this is science fiction or fantasy? As it is, this seems like a relatively mundane horror movie.

Comment: And approximately when and where did you watch this? Was it in English? Live action versus animated? Did you see this in the theaters? On TV? VHS or DVD?

Comment: its live action and kind of gave out the feeling of watching Saw.I think it might be horror. And its in english. I saw it on tv.

Comment: Both the maid and baby having white eyes without an iris, indicates something supernatural / fantastical / science fictional going on.

Comment: @SQB Depends if you believe in contact lenses or not.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Yeah, lots of babies wear white-colored contact lenses :-)

Comment: It's also a fairly standard "blindness" visual effect (resembling corneal scaring/cataracts).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots OP also mentioned the maid having an imagination. The eyes could have been a hallucination or something else non-fantastical.